# Debug why Postgres wants to use an uninstalled extension for a function

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-extensions

I recently moved a Postgres function `app_user_id` from an old, custom extension called `intpair` into a new, custom extension called `heap_exts`. This worked well except for machines I restored from a Postgres backup.

Here's the error:

```
db=> select app_user_id(1, 2);
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/intpair": No such file or directory
```

`intpair` is not installed and `heap_exts` is installed as shown by the output of `\dx`:

```
-[ RECORD 3 ]-------------------------------------------------------------
Name        | heap_exts
Version     | 1.0
Schema      | public
Description | 

-- No mention of intpair
```

The function `app_user_id` is listed in the system catalogs as being owned by `heap_exts`:

```sql
SELECT e.extname, ne.nspname AS extschema, p.proname, np.nspname AS proschema
FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension AS e
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_depend AS d ON (d.refobjid = e.oid)
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc AS p ON (p.oid = d.objid)
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ne ON (ne.oid = e.extnamespace)
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS np ON (np.oid = p.pronamespace)
WHERE d.deptype = 'e'
  AND e.extname IN ('heap_exts')
  AND p.proname = 'app_user_id'
ORDER BY 1, 3;
```

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------
extname   | heap_exts
extschema | public
proname   | app_user_id
proschema | public
```

I initially migrated the function from the old extension `intpair` into the new extension `heap_exts` with the following code:

```sql
-- version 0.1 in heap_exts--0.1.sql
ALTER EXTENSION intpair  DROP FUNCTION app_user_id(bigint, bigint);
ALTER EXTENSION heap_exts ADD FUNCTION app_user_id(bigint, bigint);
```

However, for the new machine restored via backup from the old machine, I created the `app_user_id` function directly because the old extension `intpair` no longer exists:

```
CREATE FUNCTION app_user_id(BIGINT, BIGINT) RETURNS app_user_id
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'app_user_id_make' LANGUAGE C STRICT IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Why is Postgres trying to look in the `intpair` extension for the `app_user_id` function instead of looking in `heap_exts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Postgres trying to look in the intpair extension for the app_user_id function instead of looking in heap_exts?

It sounds like you still have (or had) an entry in `pg_proc` for `app_user_id(bigint, bigint)` which points to the old function definition (`probin` would be `$libdir/intpair`).

Assuming there is an entry there, I'd guess it was somehow not properly associated with the old `intpair` extension (maybe manually added, or the code pre-dates PostgreSQL's extension functionality and the function was missed from `CREATE EXTENSION FROM unpackaged` or something) so was not removed when the extension was dropped, so is still present in your restored instance - but the associated extension library file no longer exists, of course.

The question is whether that `pg_proc` entry has somehow ended up associated with your new extension, or you have two entries in `pg_proc` for the function.

What does this modified version of your above query report?

```
SELECT e.extname, ne.nspname AS extschema, p.proname, np.nspname AS proschema, p.probin
FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension AS e
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_depend AS d ON (d.refobjid = e.oid)
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc AS p ON (p.oid = d.objid)
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ne ON (ne.oid = e.extnamespace)
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS np ON (np.oid = p.pronamespace)
WHERE d.deptype = 'e'
  AND p.proname = 'app_user_id'
ORDER BY 1, 3;
```

Comment: Nice! There's 1 entry: `extname` is `heap_exts` but `probin` is `$libdir/intpair` which verifies your hunch.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around, but it's not satisfying as an answer.  I simply tried to install the old extension. Installing the extension failed, as expected, because the function definitions overlap.

```
psql -c 'CREATE EXTENSION intpair'
ERROR:  function "app_user_id" already exists with same argument types
```

Despite the error, this seems to fix the Postgres mapping of functions to extension.